# making a c# application with a ldap database

Tags: c#, database, ldap

since monday, i'm working as an intern in a company (final year at college)
i need to make a c#project working with a ldap database

i've seen there a library made by novell that can be used.
there's also a built-in lib "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols" specially made for ldap, but there's not much documentation for it.

Has anyone worked with that lib before and can get me started or link me a place that can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use search. Plenty of samples on SO and Google

Comment: doing so, very little to find, especially if you are new at ldap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link on Directory Services description in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx